# liquid horizontal nav button with separate images and text using css

Tags: css, image

Is it possible to have a liquid navigation bar with the links having images. I am trying to have a responsive link with an image on the left and text on the right. If the size of the window changes then the button (link) will change size too. I would prefer to do this with CSS.

What I have tried so far is to have the following:

```
<div style="height:62px;margin-left:60px;border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;">
    <ul class="main_nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#me">
                <img src="img/avatar/me.png" alt="me">
                Me
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#guide">
                <img src="img/avatar/spotlight.png" alt="guide">
                Guide
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#downloads">
                <img src="img/avatar/downloads.png" alt="downloads">
                Downloads
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: More suitable on UX, or Overflow. Also you should include the CSS that you have tried. People will be more willing to intervene than start of telling you exactly what to do.

Comment: Post your CSS and put it in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ Use placeholder images. http://placehold.it